# Mercurial errors on Win XP

Tags: apache, mercurial, windows-xp

So there is an Apache server on Windows XP, and Mercurial. When i try to connect to mercuraial throw browser, i have this error:

```
[Mon Jul 09 15:15:42 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61] Premature end of script headers: hgweb.cgi
[Mon Jul 09 15:15:42 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Mon Jul 09 15:15:42 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61]   File "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/hgweb.cgi", line 16, in <module>\r
[Mon Jul 09 15:15:42 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61]     from mercurial import demandimport; demandimport.enable()\r
[Mon Jul 09 15:15:42 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61] ImportError: No module named mercurial\r
[Mon Jul 09 15:15:42 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61] File does not exist: C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
```

As I`m new in this stuff i have no idea what i should do, or read. So can you help me please.

---

[UPDATE 07\11\12]

I add link to Mercurial\Lib. Now it shows another errors:

```
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61] Premature end of script headers: hgweb.cgi
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61] Traceback (most recent call last):\r
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61]   File "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/hgweb.cgi", line 23, in <module>\r
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61]     wsgicgi.launch(application)\r
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61]   File "mercurial\\hgweb\\wsgicgi.pyc", line 76, in launch\r
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61]   File "mercurial\\hgweb\\hgwebdir_mod.pyc", line 147, in __call__\r
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61]   File "mercurial\\hgweb\\hgwebdir_mod.pyc", line 177, in run_wsgi\r
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61]   File "mercurial\\hgweb\\hgwebdir_mod.pyc", line 371, in templater\r
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61]   File "mercurial\\templater.pyc", line 392, in stylemap\r
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61] RuntimeError: No hgweb templates found in []\r
[Wed Jul 11 11:15:54 2012] [error] [client 141.206.207.61] File does not exist: C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/favicon.ico
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's telling you Mercurial isn't installed -- at least it's not in the `PYTHONPATH` that your python instance is using.  It looks like you've not correctly added the Mercurial library files to your python path as instructed here:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgWebDirStepByStep/#Mercurial_Lib_Files

Comment: Doesn`t work. I do as it was told, but nothing happens, there is the same error message.

Comment: Then you didn't do it right.  Please paste the line you're adding to the wsgi/cgi and the directory output from that directory.